Juliacall from python is not working! , Need some understanding on how to use Juliacall in Python
I'm trying to add julia library and create flask api using Juliacall.
It would be great if you guys help me to understand with these queries:
1). Is it possible to create flask api in python by using Juliacall or any other framework recommended for this ?
2). This is my code, I'm not able to get the output from this api and also no error code. Its return None
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify  
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin  
import juliacall
from juliapkg import add, resolve

add("QuasiMonteCarlo", "8a4e6c94-4038-4cdc-81c3-7e6ffdb2a71b")
add("Distributions", "31c24e10-a181-5473-b8eb-7969acd0382f")

resolve(force=False)

@app.route('/call_julia', methods=['GET'])
@cross_origin()                              
def call_julia():
    jl = juliacall.Main
    jl.seval("using QuasiMonteCarlo")
    jl.seval("using Distributions")
    lb = [0.1, -0.5]
    ub = [1.0, 20.0]
    n = 5
    s = jl.QuasiMonteCarlo.sample(n, lb, ub, jl.LatinHypercubeSample())
    print(s)
    return s


What message you get when calling the code standalone (without web service). Note that juliacall installation must be symmetric with PythonCall configuration in Julia (particularly PythonCall.jl must be configured to work with exactly the same Python installation that you use to call Julia from via juliacall. Very often machines have several Python installations and then mismatch of versions causes various errors.

strip all the juliacall stuff out of your code. it still doesn't work, or does it? that's not a complete flask application. [mre]

@ChristophRackwitz, flask application works well!. I'm not having issue with flask api . I face issue only when I use juliacall
